# Saving Data On MongoDB Using Heroku Hosted API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I've hosted my API on Horeku and I'm trying to save data on my MongoDB atlas but data doesn't seem to get sent on my MongoDB using Heroku API link on Postman, I've tried sending data using localhost and it seems to be working pretty fine, though; I can retrieve, update and delete data from MongoDB using the Heroku hosted API which means that the connection between my MongoDB and Heroku is okay.

This is the code I'm using to save data:

```
 //Register User
router.post('/', async (req, res)=>{
 
//Validate register before submitting
    const {error} = regvalidation(req.body);
    if(error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    }

//Checking If email already exists
     const emailExist = await User.findOne({Email:req.body.Email});
    if(emailExist){ 
         return res.status(400).send('Email already exists');
    }

//Hashing Password
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.Password, salt);

//Creating new User
    const user = new User({
        Fname: req.body.Fname,
        Lname: req.body.Lname,
        Email: req.body.Email,
        Password: hashedPassword
    });
    try{
    await user.save()
        res.json(user);
    }
    catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

This is also the code I'm using to retrieve data which is working as it should:

```
//Get back all Users

router.get('/', async (req, res)=> {
    try{
        const users = await User.find();
        res.json(users);
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

I've checked the DB_Connetion & token Config Vars in Heroku and everything seems to be there.

Comment: are you able to create connection to the MongoDb atlas ?

Comment: Yes, I am. It is working perfectly on my localhost.

Comment: Try doing `const newUser = await user.save(); res.json(newUser);`